# The value for key CFBundleVersion in the info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers

Tags: ipa, uploading

The error appear when I upload the ipa to the app store, and the detailed information:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000:"This bundle is invalid.The value for key CFBundleVersion [ae62f95aa0808c09a6457ae90c270cc0438d0867] in the info.plist file must be a period-separated list of at most three non-negative integers."
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it i Project > General. Use [Semver](http://www.semver.org) for versioning. And it's good for this value to match your version in iTunes Connect (you, and possibly your client wont get the email with info about mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364)

CFBundleVersion

CFBundleVersion (String - iOS, OS X) specifies the build version number of the bundle, which identifies an iteration (released or unreleased) of the bundle. The build version number should be a string comprised of three non-negative, period-separated integers with the first integer being greater than zero. The string should only contain numeric (0-9) and period (.) characters. Leading zeros are truncated from each integer and will be ignored (that is, 1.02.3 is equivalent to 1.2.3). This key is not localizable.

You need to follow above version format. Hope it helps you.